# How to recover removed packages with the purge flag?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, data-recovery

I accidently removed a package with the purge flag and it removed large parts of the Ubuntu system, including the pulseaudio server, the software center, system settings and many, many other programs and libraries.

I don't exactly know what the **purge command** does, but I'm pretty sure that it's used to remove a package along with it dependencies. So I guess it removed every package that shares dependencies with the package I wanted to remove, but it still does not make any sense.

I have the complete `dpkg.log` of removed packages, but reinstalling them via terminal is nearly impossible.

What should I do to recover the removed packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt to reinstall the entire desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

It might be easier to just go through the list of removed packages one by one and reinstall.

What ever you do this would be a good time to make a backup in case you don't already have one so when things like this happen you can just revert your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it impossible? If you have a log of removed packages, just run

```
sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3 ...
```

This should really do the trick. If you run into problems, post your dpkg.log and any errors  / problems you have encountered here.

P.S. The `--purge` option just makes sure that all config files are removed as well.

Comment: The log would be in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: So why that command removed so many packages from my system? I just wanted to remove MySQL to make a clean reinstall of it - that's why I used the purge option. I guess I should know better every command before using it.